# Terraform assigning outputs to variable or pulling output from stateful and using it

Tags: terraform

I am working with terraform and trying to output the security group ID in the form of an output and pull it from the local terraform state file and use that information in a different resource in my case it would be a aws_eks_cluster in the vpc_config session.

Answer (score 1):

In the module that has the security group:

```
output "security_group_id" {
  value = aws_security_group.a_group.id
}
```

In the module that reads the output (the backend config dependends on which backend type you are using and how it is configured):

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "security_group" {
    backend = "s3"
    config {
        bucket  = "your-terraform-state-files"
        key     = "your-state-file-key.tfstate"
        region  = "us-east-1"
    }
}

locals {
    the_security_group_id = data.terraform_remote_state.security_group.outputs.security_group_id
}
```